# Haddock, Cabal: How to include source code examples?

Tags: haskell, documentation-generation, cabal, haddock

I am the author of the [operational package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational), which includes [example code](http://projects.haskell.org/operational/examples.html). I would like this example code to be hscolored and installed *together* with the API documentation, which is generated by Haddock.

I probably have to use a custom Cabal build type and create a user hook for the Haddock phase. However, I never managed to make this work. Hence, my question is:

> How to include full modules as example code in Haddock?
>
> Could you give an example of a Cabal user hook that applies hscolor to an additional source code file `example.hs` and joins the result with the generated Haddock documentation?

Comment: I think this functionally needs to be added to Cabal.

Comment: It is ugly, but maybe you can try adding the examples to your Library. In that case Haddock should automatically be run on them. The overall support of Haddock/Cabal/Hackage for anything but the most basic documentation needs is still lacking at the moment.

Comment: Ah, I don't want to run Haddock on the examples, I just want to run hscolour on them, but install them whenever the user types `cabal haddock`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a total Haskell nube and this is a shot in the dark, but couldn't you use hscolour to output the code as HTML and then do something along the lines of *cabal haddock --executables --hyperlink-source* to include the colorized HTML?

Comment: Nice idea, it gets me something, at least. Is there a way to bake the flags into the `.cabal` file? I don't want the user to fiddle with flags.

Comment: Not sure, but ask around on the cabal-devel discussion board. Someone's bound to have solved this and can get you up and running with this: http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/cabal-devel

Comment: Hackage runs --hyperlink-source by itself nowadays, I think.